# else statement keep looping print 'not found' in python

Tags: python

I want to print not found ONCE if in the text file not found a string. But the string keeps printing not found following how many line in the file. Its because it read all the line. So it printing all not found based on how many lines in it. Is there other way to do it?

```
import os

f = open('D:/Workspace/snacks.txt', "r");
class line:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.find('chocolate') != -1:
            print "found ", line
        elif line.find('milkshake') != -1:
            print "found ", line
        else:
            print "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [break](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement in python? As the name reflects, this statement simply breaks you out of the loop.

**Eg:**

```
for line in f.readlines():
        if line.find('chocolate') != -1:
            print "found ", line

        elif line.find('milkshake') != -1:
            print "found ", line

        else:
            print "not found"
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove this line - `class line:`. Re-indent the lines below it.

Two things should help you:

1. `break` clause
2. `else` clause in `for` loop

Please read the official tutorial on [control flow](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

And then the code becomes like this

```
>>> for line in f.readlines():
...     if line.find('chocolate') != -1 or line.find('milkshake') != -1:
...             print "found ", line
...             break
... else:
...     print "not found"
...
not found
```